# Problem with form-data request with node.JS

Tags: form-data

Good morning. I will try to explains my problems. So i must create the back-side of a web site, and i can't retrieve information of a form-data request. The request contains a object and an image but when i do `console.log(req.body.key)`i obtain an wonderful **undefined**.
Below the source code of the application. The front is created with Angular and the back with Node.JS

Back-end:
+app.js

```
const express = require("express") ,
    app = express () ,
    moongoose = require("mongoose") ,
    bodyParser = require("body-parser") , 
    path = require("path") ,
    userRoute = require("./routage/user") , 
    sauceRoute = require("./routage/sauces") ;


moongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/Pekito" , {
    useNewUrlParser: true , 
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})
.then(() => {console.log("Connecte a mongo")})
.catch((error) => {console.log(error)}) ; 

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use("/api/auth/" , userRoute) ; 
app.use("/api/sauces/" , sauceRoute) ;

module.exports = app ;
```

+routes

```
exports.createSauces = (req , res , next) => { 
    console.log(req.body.sauce) ; => undefined
}
```

the front-end:

```
createSauce(sauce: Sauce, image: File) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('sauce', JSON.stringify(sauce));
      formData.append('image', image);
      this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/sauces', formData).subscribe(
        (response: { message: string }) => {
          resolve(response);
        },
        (error) => {
          reject(error);
        }
      );
    });
  }
```

So if you can explain me my error i will be very grateful to you

NB: excuse for my english, i'am a french student)

Answer (score 0):

`FormData` objects send **multipart** requests.

Your have body parsers for URL encoded and JSON encoded requests.

You need to add a body parser capable of handling multipart.

See [the documentation for the body-parser module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser):

> This does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and typically large nature. For multipart bodies, you may be interested in the following modules:
>
> - busboy and connect-busboy
> - multiparty and connect-multiparty
> - formidable
> - multer

Pick one of those modules and follow its instructions.

Comment: Thanks you very much)